# MongoEngine: difference between EmbeddedDocumentListField() and ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField())?

Tags: python, mongoengine

title. are those two statements do the same thing, or am I missing something here?

```
cars = db.EmbeddedDocumentListField(Car, default= [])
```

vs

```
cars = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField(Car), default=[])
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`EmbeddedDocumentListField` supports querying operations like `count()`, `filter()`, `delete()`, `create()` over the list of embedded documents returned. Hence, it would be more beneficial to use `EmbeddedDocumentListField()` instead of `List(EmbeddedDocumentField())`.

For more details and the list of methods refer to:

http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#embedded-document-querying

Here is an example using methods of `EmbeddedDocumentListField` showing how to add an `EmbeddedDocument` to an `EmbeddedDocumentListField` 2 levels down the primary document model:

```
model1_obj.model2_list.get(model2_id_field=model2_id).model3_list.create(**model3_data)
```

or

```
model1_obj.model2_list.filter(model2_id_field=model2_id).first().model3_list.create(**model3_data)
```

Here are model and view classes related to this code snippet:

> models.py:

```
from mongoengine import *

class Model3(EmbeddedDocument):
    field1 = StringField()
    field2 = StringField()
    field3 = StringField()

class Model2(EmbeddedDocument):
    # other fields
    model2_id_field = # Some field
    model3_list = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Model3)

class Model1(Document):
    # other fields
    model2_list = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Model2)
```

> views.py: (Implements patch method using Django rest framework)

```
class Model1AddModel3(APIView):
    def get_object(self, id):
        return Model1.objects.get(pk=id)

    def patch(self, request, id, format=None):
        model1_obj = self.get_object(id)
        #
        # Validate request.data here
        # Extract model2 identifier and model3 data from request.data
        # e.g.:
        # model2_id = request.data['model2id']
        # model3_data = {'field1': 'a', 'field2': 'a', 'field3': 'a', }
        #
        model1_obj.model2_list.get(model2_id_field=model2_id).model3_list.create(**model3_data)
        #
        # You can also use:
        # model1_obj.model2_list.filter(model2_id_field=model2_id).first().model3_list.create(**model3_data)
        #
        model1_obj.save()
        return Response(some_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```